# Cassandra paging on timestamp ordered data: filtering by clustering key vs native pagination

Tags: cassandra, pagination

I have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE events_by_user (
   user_id text, 
   date timestamp,
   event_id text,
   event_data text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), date, event_id)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC, event_id ASC);
```

and I want to do pagination on it. 
So, query pattern could be like: select first 10 events, select next 10 events and so on.
I see two options here:

1. native manual paging https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/paging/
2. use limit + filter on clustering key: 
   `SELECT * FROM events_by_user WHERE user_id = :id AND date < :since LIMIT 10`

How cassandra will handle it on large number of data in partition?
Second approach seems more flexible, because data can be filtered by random dates.

Answer (score 2):

Second Approach is is more efficient and flexible to use.
With the First Approach you can't jump to any state but with 2nd one you can.

And there is a limitation with First One from DataStax doc 

`The paging state can only be reused between perfectly identical statements (same query string, same bound parameters). Altering the contents of the paging state or trying to set it on a different statement will cause this method to fail.`

And I have inserted 10 Million events with your schema into a single userid.
Here is the performance

```
|------------------------------------|
| Driver Paging | Cluster Key Paging | 
| --------------|--------------------|
|  1345026 ms   |      1210296 ms    |
|------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you share the code of benchmarks and sample data?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your query `SELECT * FROM events_by_user WHERE user_id = :id AND date < :since LIMIT 10` it may cause you to miss some rows - as the `event_id` is also used in the clustering key. 
A simple example would be a user_id= that only has a single date= and 100 rows with different event_id (all using the same date=). In this case the query will return the 10 first rows and the next query will miss the rest not return anything.

Pagination is done by the driver in a very similar way to the queries you are trying to execute, by passing additional data paging_state. Please note:

1. Pagination does not require to return back page size results - it may return less and may take into account performance related optimization when returning results.
2. The code of option 2 will continue reading the next page as long as the number of returned rows is equal to the limits. Pagination will need one less query in the cases in which a partitions rows divide by the limits request  (e.g. `#rows % limits = 0`). In these cases the last iteration in option 2 will need to try and fetch the "next page" and get back 0 rows,  while the driver may use an extra bit returned with the data marking that there is no additional data.

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/native_protocol_v3.spec

> 8. Result paging
>
>    The protocol allows for paging the result of queries. For that, the
>      QUERY and   EXECUTE messages have a  value that
>      indicate the desired   page size in CQL3 rows.
>
>    If a positive value is provided for , the result
>      set of the   RESULT message returned for the query will contain at
>      most the    first rows of the query result. If that
>      first page of result   contains the full result set for the query, the
>      RESULT message (of kind `Rows`)   will have the Has_more_pages flag
>      *not* set. However, if some results are not   part of the first response, the Has_more_pages flag will be set and the result   will
>      contain a  value. In that case, the  value
>      should be used in a QUERY or EXECUTE message (that has the *same*
>      query than   the original one or the behavior is undefined) to
>      retrieve the next page of   results.
>
>    Only CQL3 queries that return a result set (RESULT message with a
>      Rows `kind`)   support paging. For other type of queries, the
>       value is   ignored.
>
>    Note to client implementors:
>
>    - While  can be as low as 1, it will likely be detrimental
>        to performance to pick a value too low. A value below 100 is probably too
>        low for most use cases.
>    - Clients should not rely on the actual size of the result set returned to
>        decide if there is more result to fetch or not. Instead, they should always
>        check the Has_more_pages flag (unless they did not enabled paging for the query
>        obviously). Clients should also not assert that no result will have more than
>         results. While the current implementation always respect
>        the exact value of , we reserve ourselves the right to return
>        slightly smaller or bigger pages in the future for performance reasons.
>    - The  is specific to a protocol version and drivers should not
>        send a  returned by a node using the protocol v3 to query a node
>        using the protocol v4 for instance.